# Переменные класса как замена глобальных переменных

Tags: python, ооп, архитектура

Добрый день.
Возник вопрос, насколько хорошей практикой является использование переменной класса как своего рода глобальную переменную?

Поясню примером.
Для одной моей задачи мне нужно было создавать класс, объекты которого будут получать уникальный номер при создании. Я сделал это так:

```
class A(object):

    _counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = A._counter
        A._counter += 1
```

Это работает, но насколько это хорошо с точки зрения правильных принципов архитектуры?

Это ведь чем-то очень похоже на глобальную переменную получается.

А можно ведь сделать, чтобы экземпляры объекта не только айдишники таким образом получали, но и потом коммуницировались с другими экземплярами через переменные класса. Насколько правильно делать так?

А если в переменную положить не просто значение, а сложный объект - то это вообще синглтон получится.

А ещё к переменной класса могут обращаться не только его экземпляры, но и какой-то внешний код. Так, наверное, вообще не стоит делать?

Comment: Классы для этого и создавались, чтобы передавать и взаимодействовать со сложными объектами. Для простых переменных как счетчик лучше глобальные.  Явное лучше, чем неявное. Простое лучше, чем сложное. Сложное лучше, чем запутанное.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ответить на этот вопрос это все ровно что ответить на вопрос "зачем нужны статические переменные в классе".

Answer (score 1):

```
import uuid
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        ob = object.__new__(cls)
        setattr(ob, 'uuid', uuid.uuid1().__str__())
        return ob

o1 = A()
o2 = A()
print(o1.uuid, o2.uuid)
43fcaa9a-63ac-11e6-9057-1c6f6592d67b 43fd46da-63ac-11e6-97a8-1c6f6592d67b
```

можно и так, но зачем

Comment: так не зачем, но если добавить сложносоставной объект, то будет зачем.